# JonkyKong's SideMenu 'No Such Module' error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift4, carthage

I'm working on a fairly large `iOS` project using `Swift 4.0` for which I require a side menu and *JonkyKong's* implementation of it seems ideal.

I tried install it via cocoapods but I always get :

`'No Such Module'` on the `Import SideMenu` line of code.

Cleaned the build using

```
Option+Command+Shift+K
```

Still no luck.

Deintegrated the pod install and re-installed.

Still wont work, so I decided to go for a Carthage install to find myself in the same situation, even after cleaning the build and re-starting the whole project several times.

I've gone through the README and found no answers there.

Before raising this as an Issue I'd like to know if anyone out there knows of an answer for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try Building. Xcode doesn't recognize CocoaPods modules until after the first build.

Answer (score 1):

I've met this problem aswell when i build on iOS 10. 
Then i found that it cause by a wrong configuration in build setting.
The project's deployment target i set to 10.0 
but pod SideMenu's deployment target is 12.0. 
Change the pod SideMenu's deployment target to 10.0 resolve my problem.
Hope that it's help U.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this out:
Go to Product > Schemes > New Scheme...
Select the name of your Cocoapod then click OK.
After you do this, build the project (click cmd + B)

This worked for me.